# PHP Shopping Cart Variable and Object errors

Tags: php, arrays, object, shopping-cart

I need help to eliminate the errors Im getting.  I have a shopping cart that is displayed on the products page by way of a cart update page.  I get the below pair of errors (Notices) for every product listed:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: obj in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project2\browseproducts.php on line 89

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project2\browseproducts.php on line 89
```

When I click on any of the Add to Cart buttons, nothing is added to the cart and I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Stock in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project2\cart_update.php on line 25
```

My code is:

```
  <?php
            $user = "root";
            $password = "";
            $database = "WebStore";
            mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $password);
            @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
            $current_url = base64_encode("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS ORDER BY Category";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            if($result === FALSE) {
            die(mysql_error());} // TODO: better error handling    

            // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<form method='post' action='cart_update.php'>";
                echo "<td>" . "<img src=" .$row['IconURL'] . "alt=" .$row['Name'] ."/>" . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Descr'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . '$' . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Stock'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td> <button class='add_to_cart'>Add to Cart</button> </td>";
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />'; 
                echo "</form>";
                echo "</tr>\n";
            }

            mysql_close();
            ?>
        </table>
```

Some of my Cart Update code:

```
//add item in shopping cart
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
    $product_code   = filter_var($_POST["product_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //product code
    $Stock    = filter_var($_POST["Stock"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product code
    $return_url     = \base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url

    //limit quantity for single product
    if($Stock < 1){
        die('<div align="center">We are currently out of stock<br /><a href="browseproducts.php/">Back To Products</a>.</div>');
    }
    $queryy = "SELECT TOP 1 Name,Price FROM Products WHERE product_code='$product_code'";
    //MySqli query - get details of item from db using product code
    $results = mssql_query($queryy);
    $obj = mssql_fetch_object($results);
```

Aaaany help would be appreciated!

Comment: Read the error message: __Undefined variable: obj in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project2\browseproducts.php__. The error message tells you __exactly__ where your problem is. Go there, fix it.

Comment: I understand the what, I dont know the HOW.  Do I add    if(isset($_POST['Stock']))   below the while statement?  Im new to php and confused.

Comment: To be quite honest, there is too much to answer here. In the first snippet you're referring to the variable $obj which doesn't exist. Clearly, something should exist but where you get it from isn't obvious without the database schema to look at. Your $Stock variable is initialised from values posted to the form. You probably need another hidden field in your first form with that information. There are other problems: you're using `mysql_*()` in one script but your comments refer to `mysqli_*()` and your other script uses `mssql_*()`, which is another beast altogether.

Comment: ...more. You've also got issues with use of deprecated functions and exposure to SQL injection to worry about. And that's just in the snippets you've posted. Good luck